# jasmine-reporters : is it possible to add custom attributes

Tags: node.js, xml, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

my reporting tool expecting string "Passed"/ "Failed" for each test.

is there any solution work around to add custom attributes ?

**Expected :**

<testsuites disabled="0" errors="0" failures="0" tests="2" status: "Passed" time="29.76">
<testsuites disabled="0" errors="0" failures="0" tests="2" status: "Failed" time="29.76">

Actual :

Comment: Something like :    var jasmineReporters = require("jasmine-reporters");
 var jasmineReporters = require("jasmine-reporters");
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        savePath: path.join(process.cwd(), "./Log/junitResults/"),
        consolidateAll: false,
        spec: { displayStacktrace: true , status : true},
  
        suiteDone: function(result) {
          status :  result.status
        },
      

      })
    );

Comment: whats the actual

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuites disabled="0" errors="0" failures="0" tests="1" time="8.964">
 <testsuite name="Create User Cookies" timestamp="2021-02-23T12:09:03" hostname="localhost" time="8.964" errors="0" tests="1" skipped="0" disabled="0" failures="0">
  <testcase classname="Create User Cookies" name="Load URL" time="8.951" />
 </testsuite>
</testsuites>

Comment: actual ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^